# how to make netrw list .h and .c files together as pairs?

Tags: vim, netrw

Can netrw :E display .h and .c files together as pairs?

For example:

```
file1.h
file1.c
file2.h
file2.c
file3.h
file3.c
```

Currently my netrw :E list the files in this sequence:

```
file1.h
file2.h
file3.h
file1.c
file2.c
file3.c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand from `:h netrw-sort-sequence`, the `g:netrw_sort_sequence` setting by default prioritizes `.h` files over `.c` files.

You can add the following to your `vimrc` file to change the default behavior:

```
let g:netrew_sort_sequence = '[\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=,\.[a-np-z]$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$'
```

Note: the lack of `.h` and `.c` extensions.

#### Aside about switching files

There are many (nicer in my opinion) ways to switching between files apart from using a file explorer like netrw aka `:Explore`. To name a few:

- Fuzzy Finder e.g. [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)
- [Projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) for well structured projects
- Using `:find` and `'path'`
- Using `%` to represent current file. See `:h :_%`
- Using `<tab>` completion (as well as `<c-d>`) with `:e` (also accepts globs)

For C projects you have some nice `.c` <-> `.h` switching options.

**Plugins**

Switching plugins like [fswitch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) which is a C/C++ .h/.c switcher. Please see `:h fswitch-setup` for more information.

There are a few other plugins that do similar things: [altr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4202) and [a.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) to name a few.

**Vanilla Vim**

If plugins are not your thing then you can use `%` tricks. e.g. `:sp %<.h`

Or maybe a quick and dirty mapping:

```
nnoremap <f4> :e %:p:s,.h$,.X123X,:s,.c$,.h,:s,.X123X$,.c,<cr>
```

For more information see the following vim wiki page: [Easily switch between source and header file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file)

Comment: Thanks Peter,
The "Single line solution" on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file is nice and simple:
 hit <F4> key to toggle between .h and .cpp files
I will use that.